# ImageView may return Null?

Tags: android, nullable, findviewbyid

I have a fragment that is half image and then half text.

Trying to assign the `ImageView` and the `TextView` but it says:

> Might give null

and when I run the app it does not run.

I included the Java and XML files for fragment and included the mainActivity java.

Fragment code:

```
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import android.view.View;


    public class headercode extends Fragment implements Runnable{

        ImageView image;
        TextView text;


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            if(getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView ) != null)
            {

                image = (ImageView)getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            }
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag, container, false);
        }

        public void run(){

            text.setText("Test");

        }
    }
```

Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#692f2f">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="269dp"
        android:id="@+id/text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Button;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener   {




    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();



        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment) != null){

            headercode header = new headercode();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment,header).commit();




        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);//This is the setting top right
        return true;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.Technology) {



        } else if (id == R.id.Opinion) {




        } else if (id == R.id.travel) {



        } else if (id == R.id.politics) {



        }else if(id == R.id.Home){



        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: You're asking a duplicate question. And it is not related to Android Studio (I will gladly edit your post :P). Please always Google before posting a question, it saves your time and ours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697915/why-custom-image-view-s-findviewbyid-returns-null

Comment: The Lint warning is to say that the `findViewById()` can return a `null`. This is just to let you know that a null should be expected. Read about it here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936907/why-android-studio-has-this-nullable-thing. But your problem is read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697915/why-custom-image-view-s-findviewbyid-returns-null

Answer (score 1):

For fragment you should inflate first your xml in the onCreateView method, you get your view and you can find your corresponding ImageView:

```
View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag, container, false);

ImageView myImage = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.layout.my_image);

return myView;
```

In the xml you should add an id to the iamgeView in order to get it:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />
```

Comment: Correct, he also haven't given an `id` to his imageview above.

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to assign the ImageView and the textView but it says Might give
>   null error and when i run the app it does not run.

That's a lint warning informing you that `findViewById` could return null. If your xml contains the `id` you are looking for, you don't have anything to worry about.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView ) != null)
```

`getView()` returns the `View` the `onCreateView` returns, therefore you can't use `getView()` inside `onCreateView`. Override `onViewCreate` instead, and its parameter `View` to perform your `findViewById` calls

Answer (score 0):

In the fragment you first need to infalte the view and then assing values to its content

Example:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag, container, false);
ImageView image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
tv.setText("Test");

// Here you will perform all the actions that you want to perform and then in the end return the view like below

return rootView;
}
```